# How can I use git grep with regular expressions?

Tags: git, grep

I have used `git grep` for years to search for fixed strings and haven't used it much for doing regular expression searches.

I have places in the code with non-localized strings.  For example:

```
   JLabel label =  buildLabel("Alphabet");
```

In this case `buildLabel()` is an inherited utility method.  There are also `buildBoldLabel()`, `buildMultiLineLabel()`, and `buildTextArea()`.

So I would like to search my code for uses of these methods without a lookup for the localized string.  The correct call should be:

```
   JLabel label =  buildLabel(getString("Alphabet"));
```

I am very familiar with regular expressions and I see that `git grep` supports Perl character classes.  So I figured that it would be very easy:

`$ git grep -P "buildLabel(\"\w+\")"`

This returns no results.  So I tried it without the Perl extension.

`$ git grep "buildLabel(\"[a-zA-Z_]+\")"`

Still ... no results. I verified that I could search with a fixed string.

`$ git grep "buildLabel(\"Alphabet\")"`

That returned the instance in the code that I already knew existed.  However ...

`$ git grep -P "buildLabel(\"Alphabet\")"`

Returns no results.

I also tried changing the quote characters and got the same results.

`$ git grep -P 'buildLabel("\w+")'` ... no results

`$ git grep -P 'buildLabel("Alphabet")'` ... no results

`$ git grep 'buildLabel("Alphabet")'` ... 1 expected result

I tried on Linux with the same results.

UPDATE:

Thanks to @wiktor-stribiżew commenting that with PCRE the parens need to be escaped (I am always confused by that).

`$ git grep -P 'buildLabel\("\w+"\)'` ... returns 1 expected result.

However, why don't these work?

`$ git grep 'buildLabel("[a-zA-Z_]+")'`

`$ git grep 'buildLabel\("[a-zA-Z_]+"\)'`

`$ git grep 'buildLabel\("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_]*"\)'` (in case + isn't implemented)

---

So what am I doing wrong with `git grep`?  Or is it broken?

FYI: I am using git version 2.35.1 from Homebrew on macOS Big Sur.

Comment: In PCRE regex, `(` and `)` must be escaped to match literal parentheses. It must be something like `git grep -P 'buildLabel\("\w+"\)'`

Comment: Re: "is it broken?"  Chances are that the tool that has been used by millions every day for years is not what's broken.

Comment: @AndyLester: Yeah, I can't believe it would be broken. But I couldn't figure out how to get it to work.  It is POSSIBLE that something is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regex vs. fixed string search**

Please refer to the [git grep help](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep):

```
-G
--basic-regexp
Use POSIX extended/basic regexp for patterns. Default is to use basic regexp.
```

So, by default, `git grep` treats the pattern string as a POSIX BRE regex, **not as a fixed string**.

To make `git grep` treat the pattern as a fixed string you need `-F`:

```
-F
--fixed-strings
Use fixed strings for patterns (don’t interpret pattern as a regex).
```

**Regex issues**

You can enable PCRE regex syntax with `-P` option, and in that case you should refer to [PCRE documentation](https://www.pcre.org/).

In your `git grep -P "buildLabel(\"\w+\")"`, the parentheses must be escaped in order to be matched as literal parentheses, i.e. it should be `git grep -P "buildLabel\(\"\w+\"\)"`.

In `git grep 'buildLabel("[a-zA-Z_]+")'`, you are using the [POSIX BRE regex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), and `+` is parsed as a literal `+` char, not as a *one or more* quantifier. You can use `git grep 'buildLabel("[a-zA-Z_]\{1,\}")'` in POSIX BRE though. If it is a GNU grep, you could use `git grep 'buildLabel("[a-zA-Z_]\+")'` (not sure it works with `git`).

The `git grep 'buildLabel\("[a-zA-Z_]+"\)'` does not work because `\(...\)` (escaped pair of parentheses) define a *capturing group* and do not thus match literal parentheses.

The `git grep -e 'buildLabel\("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_]*"\)'` is the same POSIX BRE, to make it a [POSIX ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), you need to use the `-E` option, `git grep -E 'buildLabel\("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_]*"\)'`. Or `git grep -E 'buildLabel\("[a-zA-Z_]+"\)'`, the unescaped `+` is a quantifier in POSIX ERE.

Also, see [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078/3832970)

Comment: I have been developing for almost 30 years and I thought I understood RegEx.  I guess my knowledge is pre-POSIX.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: The `-e` in the previous example was not intended to be `-E`.  It was just an accidental inclusion from trying things out with the `-e` and without it (the documentation has `-e` before `<pattern>` and seems to be optional).

Comment: @chrish `-e` just means the next thing is the pattern. If the pattern does not start with `-`, it is optional.

Comment: I think you removed a link (https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) which was more helpful for explaining POSX BRE and ERE in regards to + and ? matching.  Specifically this quote:  "Some implementations support \? and \+ as an alternative syntax to \{0,1\} and \{1,\}, but \? and \+ are not part of the POSIX standard."  Maybe I found the link through another post, but I thought it was in here.

Comment: @chrish I did not remove it as I did not add it. Surely, [that regex site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) is really helpful, too.

Comment: @chrish: yes, REs get absurdly complex when you consider all the different flavors ("regex buddy ... 269 flavors ..."!). Git can do Perl REs but only if compiled with Perl support.